# Git merge conflict | how to manage branches to make them isolated from each other but also use dependent code from each other

Tags: git, branch, bitbucket

1. I have a master branch.
2. I created a branch named `Issue1` from master. After completing `Issue1` I created another issue named as `Issue2` 
   from master, note that I didn't create it on top of `Issue1`.
3. Reason for step 2 is that, while pushing issues on production, there might be a condition where I don't have to merge code 
   from `Issue1` but if I create it on top of `Issue1` there could be a problem while I will push `Issue2`, so commits from 
   both branches will be pushed to production (master).
4. Thats why I'm creating each issue from master branch to make each issue isolated from each other.
5. But the problem is while working on `Issue1` I modified file and created common methods or something that is also required 
   for `Issue2`. Now in that case I don't have a code from `Issue1`.

So from above, its good to create `Issue2` on top of `Issue1` but that way my requirement is not fulfilling its purpose. 
I read about cheery picking. Not sure if its applicable here.

Also if I modified index.php inside `Issue1` and added link and on `Issue2` i modified same file and added another link, 
there will be conflict. So I can't prevent it, although I knew I have modified this file on both branches.I have to deal with 
resolving the conflicts, I can't pevent it until I create it on top of `Issue1`, but my second purpose will suffer in such case.

What would be the best way of resolving this. I want both my purposes to be resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider making 3rd branch, f.e. `Feature1` or `Common1`, and writing common code there. Then you can merge this branch both to `Issue1` and `Issue2` (and master, ofc).

I believe it's very git-way - issue-related code is in the Issue branches and common code is in the Common branch.

Edit1:
The final structure I'm proposing:

```
   master
     |
   Common
    /  \
Issue1 Issue2
```

In case you already have Issues, it may look like this:

```
        master
      /   |   \
Issue1 Common1 Issue2 
  |    /  |   \    /
  Merge   |    Merge 
    |     |      |
Issue1 updated Issue2 
       common
```

**Edit2: Another explanation.**

You have master:

```
var x = 1;
var y = 2;
print(x+y);
```

lets say your Issue1 should look like:

```
var x = 1;
var y = 3;
printLine(x+y);

function printLine (x) { return print(x + 'line'); }
```

and your Issue2 should look like:

```
var x = 1;
var y = 4;
printLine(x+y);

function printLine (x) { return print(x + 'line'); }
```

then you make Common1 branch as this:

```
var x = 1;
var y = 2;
printLine(x+y);

function printLine (x) { return print(x + 'line'); }
```

So your workflow will look like this:

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b common1
//make changes as in Common1
git commit -am common1
git checkout issue1
git merge common1
git checkout issue2
git merge common1
//then you can work on issues. f.e. making changes in issue1
git checkout issue1
//code, code
git commit -am issue1
//if you want to update common methods
git checkout common1
//update
git commit -am updated-common1
git checkout issue1
git merge common1
git checkout issue2
git merge common2
```

Comment: Ok, and how to prevent future conflicts when you know that you have to modify same file on Issue 2 which was modified on Issue 1 at same line.

Comment: And what about Cherry picking, if I create Issue2 on top of Issue1. Is it even possible with my requirements. This will break my second requirement. But cherry picking may help but is it possible?

Comment: So, let's say you start with master. You create Common branch/commit with common code (which should be in production in both of your issues.) Then you create both Issues on top of this Common branch. In case you already have these two branches and want to move same code from them to another branch -- easiest way is that you should manually create Common branch, copy common code to it and then merge common into your issues branches. I've made edit to show you final structure

Comment: But code from Issue1 should not be pushed to master but Issue2 (that you are saying to create common from both, but code from issue 1 should not be there right now). I will create Issue3 on master and edit same code on same line and issue will be there. Issue 1 has to be pushed next week, so that code will remain there and side by side I have to keep on working on other issues may be on same line. I hope you are getting my point here.

Comment: Check out my diagrams, I've tried to explain graphically. You have some shared code in Issue1 and Issue2, and this is the code you should put into Issue3. Not more, only new common methods. Then you merge Issue3 into Issue1 and work in the Issue1, not touching common methods. Also you merge Issue3 into Issue2 and work on Issue2, not touching common methods. If you need to update common code - you work on Issue3, then merge it into your Issue 1 and 2. Issue3 will be "shared branch with common code", utility commits safe to merge into any Issue

Comment: Ok, I will try it step by step and will give you an update on this.